# Compare previous state

Tags: redux

In [issue 303](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/303#issuecomment-125184409) in the Redux repo, Dan Abramov gives an example of a function that can wrap a store’s `subscribe` method in order to pass the previous state to the subscriber.

```
function observeStore(store, select, onChange) {
  let currentState;

  function handleChange() {
    let nextState = select(store.getState());
    if (nextState !== currentState) {
      currentState = nextState;
      onChange(currentState);
    }
  }

  let unsubscribe = store.subscribe(handleChange);
  handleChange();
  return unsubscribe;
}
```

For some reason, this doesn't work for me. The first time my `onChange` handler is called `currentState` is `undefined`, as I’d expect. However, on each subsequent state change, the properties of `currentState` are equivalent in value (`==`) to those of `nextState`. The two state objects aren’t the same object, though because `nextState === currentState` evaluates to `false`.

I’m likely missing something really obvious. How do I capture the previous state in a closure?

Comment: `==` isn't "equivalence in value". You can easily check that `{} != {}`. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons

Comment: What I was trying to convey is that the two states are definitely different objects (`!==`), but the property that I changed is equal in the two instances. It’s like the observer sees two copies of the updated state, not the old and the new state.

Comment: Argh! I must be doing something else wrong in my application because http://jsbin.com/xebomi/edit?js,console illustrates that it works. (Well, with one modification to Dan’s original code.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that my reducer wasn’t actually creating a new instance of the state, i.e. I was mutating the state in place, rather than returning a new copy. My reducer code was something like:

```
const newState = Object.assign({}, state);
newState.my.prop = …;
return newState;
```

However, `Object.assign` and ES2015 destructuring assignment only do *shallow* copies, meaning they only affect one level deep. In my app, the state I was updating was three levels deep. I used a quick, dirty, ugly hack in my reducer to test my theory:

```
const newState = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state)); // <-- Yuck!
newState.my.prop = …;
return newState;
```

Don’t try that at home. This was my first clue, though. A proper implementation would use something like Facebook’s [Immutable](http://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/) library to ensure each mutation results in a fresh clone.

Comment: You can also use [Immutability Helpers](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html) in your reducers without need of using immutable-js throughout the project

Comment: I just got burnt by a state mutation too. I needed deep-freeze (npm) to find the issue.